# Get external email from action "mailto"-form

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, mailto

Is it possible to pick out the email adress that a "mailto"-form will send an external email to?

example from this (swedish "ebay" - ad)
http://www2.blocket.se/ar/form/0?id=52142799&ca=1_8&l=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  The email will be processed at the back end, and there's no way to tell by looking at the source of the web page what will happen there.

Comment: I could almost finger that out, that the source page not will give me the answer. I'm thinking some other solution?
1. See the network traffic?
2. add my "fake" email account copy receiver, and see something from the email header?

or is there "absolutely" no way?

thanks for the fast answer btw!

Comment: The network traffic will be between the webserver and the recipient's mailserver, so you won't be able to see it.  If you can get it to cc: you, then you might be able to see something useful from the headers... but you can't know how the back end makes the decision as to where the email goes.